# Images appear distorted in a stack view

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, uistackview

I have three images aligned in a horizontal stack view. The stack view is aligned to the left, bottom, and right margins and given a constant height. When the images are set to aspect fit the simulator works great but they don't take up the full height. On aspect fill they take up the full height and appear correctly in preview. But when I run the app in simulator the layout is wrong and some images are too big. It's like the width of the image is expanding despite the stack view trying to hold it in place. How can I correct this?

[screenshot of xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k02sS.png)

[screenshot of simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLYOK.png)

Comment: Do you have any image or code to show?

Comment: I added screen shots, please let me know if you need more info.  I'm new to coding so thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The images are probably drawn correctly but they are drawn outside the bounds of the image view.

For all the image views you have to set `clipToBounds` ("Clip subviews" in Interface Builder) to `YES` and the image will stop being rendered outside the bounds of the view.